# Why won't my SimpleDateFormat convert correctly?

Tags: java, parsing, date, simpledateformat

I have my Date as String: **2014-06-23 22:00**

To get the Date as java.util.date I parse it by using SimpleDateFormat

```
Date listDate = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm",Locale.GERMANY);
listDate = sdf.parse(gameList.get(position).getTime());
```

but my output

```
    System.out.println(listDate)
```

is **2014-04-118 19:37**

What's going on here??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DD should be dd (in small)  below are the available formats in Java7

[image]